# Why am I getting an error on Heroku that suggests I need to migrate my app to Bamboo?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, heroku

When I type: git push heroku master, this is what happens

```
$:sample_app git push heroku master
Counting objects: 110, done.
Delta compression using up to 2 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (94/94), done.
Writing objects: 100% (110/110), 87.48 KiB, done.
Total 110 (delta 19), reused 0 (delta 0)

-----> Heroku receiving push
-----> Rails app detected
 !     This version of Rails is only supported on the Bamboo stack
 !     Please migrate your app to Bamboo and push again.
 !     See http://docs.heroku.com/bamboo for more information
 !     Heroku push rejected, incompatible Rails version

error: hooks/pre-receive exited with error code 1
To git@heroku.com:blazing-frost-89.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@heroku.com:blazing-frost-89.git'
```

My .gems file:

```
rails --version 2.3.8
```

My .git/config file:

```
[core]
  repositoryformatversion = 0
  filemode = true
  bare = false
  logallrefupdates = true
  ignorecase = true
[remote "origin"]
  url = git@github.com:csmeder/sample_app.git
  fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
[remote "heroku"]
  url = git@heroku.com:blazing-frost-89.git
  fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/heroku/*
```

Comment: Lol; Git, Heroku, Bamboo; sounds like bad anime

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like it says, Rails 2.3.8 is only available on their Bamboo stack. I think it's because Bamboo is slated to become the default stack in the near future, and Rails has only been upgraded on that stack.

Comment: I don't understand. If I use the following commands:
185-86-134:sample_app heroku create
Creating blazing-frost-89.... done
Created http://blazing-frost-89.heroku.com/ | git@heroku.com:blazing-frost-89.git
Git remote heroku added
185-86-134:sample_app git push heroku master


You think it would create itself on the correct stack? I have to create it and then manually migrate it? It seems like something is wrong. Shouldn't it create on Bamboo if it really needs to be on Bamboo.

Comment: The Aspen stack is still the default, for the time being. When you create a project on Heroku, it can't know your project requirements (i.e., you may be using an older version of Rails) until you actually push.